# How to get I/O priority to work on Ubuntu?

Tags: performance, io, scheduler

Ubuntu has `ionice`, but as far as I can tell, it does absolutely nothing.

I suspect this is because [Ubuntu replaced cfq with deadline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784442/why-does-ubuntu-16-04-set-all-drive-io-schedulers-to-deadline) and [deadline doesn't support priorities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160081/56781).

Is there any possible way to have prioritized I/O on Ubuntu anymore?

EDIT: The context is that I have a database restore that easily consumes all my I/O and renders my system unusable until it has finished. I'd like it to remain usable for other tasks.

Comment: What happens if you renice the database restore **process**? Will it still consume all you I/O?

Comment: Did you try `ionice -c idle myprocess`? Could you describe the steps and your hadware (`inxi -SMD -! 31 -y 80`)? `iotop` while running?

Comment: you can change the scheduler with `sudo echo cfq > /sys/block/<blockdevice>/queue/scheduler` for an immediate change or for a more permanent one, add `elevator=cfq` to your grub cmd_line. AFAIK cfq is the only scheduler that supports io priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your scheduler from `deadline`to `cfq`.

You can do that per blockdevice and non permanent via

```
sudo echo cfq > /sys/block/<blockdevice>/queue
```

Or for the whole system, permanent via `grub`, with adding the `elevator=cfq`parameter to the grub commandline options.

[This is an excellent post](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/783023) explaining how you can do that.

What the drawbacks of such a change are is [better covered elsewhere.](http://www.saujs.sakarya.edu.tr/tr/download/article-file/595488)

The TL;DR is

> According to the test results, each scheduler has different advantages
>   over others. CFQ scheduler is suitable for the systems that require
>   balanced I/O access and do not need process prioritization. Deadline 
>   scheduler  has  better  performance  on read-intensive works. Noop is
>   for the systems on the cloud or hypervisors. BFQ performs better on
>   interactive  use-case  scenarios.  Noop  is  the simplest scheduler
>   and it is considered to have the potential for optimized new
>   implementations targeting SSD block devices.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be helpfull for Ubuntu 20.04, which lacks the cfq scheduler:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1350605

From that answer:

Ubuntu 20.04 is using Kernel 5.4 (with HWE: 5.8) with only the `mq-deadline` scheduler compiled in.

You can check it by viewing `/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`. The active scheduler has square brackets around. If there are other schedulers compiled in the kernel they are also shown.

Example:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none

# uname -r
5.4.0-26-generic
```

The `mq-deadline` scheduler does not support the mechanism used by `ionice` at the moment, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160081/27458

## Solution: Switch to BFQ scheduler

The `bfq` scheduler does not need to be compiled in the kernel, it can be loaded afterwards using a kernel module.

Switch to the BFQ scheduler:

```
# modprobe  "bfq"
# echo "bfq" > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
# echo "bfq" > /etc/modules-load.d/bfq.conf
# echo 'ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/60-scheduler.rules
```

Check:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
mq-deadline [bfq] none
```

It is probably a good idea to also do a reboot and check again.

### BFQ not available on "virtual" kernel

If you are using a "virtual" kernel, you will probably not have the  `bfq` kernel module available because it does not include the `linux-modules-extra-5.xxx` package.

You can solve this by switching to the "generic-HWE" kernel:

```
# sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-20.04  linux-tools-generic-hwe-20.04
# reboot
```

After reboot you should be on kernel `5.8.0-xxx-generic`. You can check this:

```
# uname -r
5.8.0-59-generic
```

Now you can apply the above solution.

## Alternative solution: Systemd scope

If you don't want to switch the IO scheduler, you can use a Systemd scope with a lower IO weight.

Create a file `/usr/local/bin/mh_ionice` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( EUID == 0 )); then USERMODE=''; else USERMODE='--user'; fi
systemd-run \
  --collect \
  --quiet \
  --scope \
  $USERMODE \
  --nice=19 \
  --property="IOAccounting=yes" \
  --property="IOWeight=1" \
  "$@"
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/mh_ionice
```

Now you can run:

```
mh_ionice  [heavy_command] [arg] [arg] [arg]
```