# Why are writes on an NVME slower under Linux than under Windows?

Tags: ssd, nvme, gnome-disk-utility

I am using a [970 EVO 1TB NVME SSD](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/494791/Samsung-SSD-970-EVO-1TB) (2500MB/s SLC-Cached (1200MB/s TLC)) and a MX300 SATA SSD in my system.

After running some benchmarks I realized that the NVME SSD is not as fast as I hoped it would be.

According to the gnome disk benchmark I get and avg. write speed of 620 MB/s on my NVME and 499 MB/s on my SATA SSD. I get the same results when copying files manually.

Does NVME SSDs have to be configured specially in Linux?

[image]
[image]

I installed Windows and copied a 12 GB file on both systems. Under Windows I have about twice the performance as under Linux.

[image]
[image]

I found a thread with a similar issue https://askubuntu.com/a/1271465/961371 but without a solution.

EDIT: Testing different Kernels

On the latest Ubuntu live USB stick, I get bad speed, but on a Linux Mint 18.2 (Kernel 4.8.0.-53) live USB stick I get good speeds (see second image).

```
cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler
4.8.0.-53 = none
newer kernel = [none] mq-deadline kyber
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can not confirm. Ubuntu 20.04 and 970 EVO Plus 1TB NVME here and get speed of 1,1GB/s writing and 3.1GB/s reading. Even though its Luks encrypted. Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and firmware for both SSD? What format is partition(s) you are writing into? What secheduler are you using in Linux. `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-415-iosched&num=1 Are you using noatime in fstab to mount Linux partition? http://www.velobit.com/storage-performance-blog/bid/126135/Effects-Of-Linux-IO-Scheduler-On-SSD-Performance
This basically means that data may be written to the disk before the journal. Speed over safety see man tune2fs Do not know whether NTFS uses speed or safety as its default.

Comment: @pLumo Did you benchmark with gnome disks or maybe fio ? Can you take a screenshot ?

Comment: @oldfred both times the scheduler was `none` the old kernel reported `[none] mq-deadline kyber` and the new one `none`

Comment: I am using `[mq-deadline]`, but that was default from install. I do change mount of any partition on SSD to noatime in fstab. If writing to NTFS it will be slower. Older question, not sure if still current: https://askubuntu.com/questions/784442/why-does-ubuntu-16-04-set-all-drive-io-schedulers-to-deadline

Comment: Can confirm. Ubuntu 20.04 slow (~700mb/s) speed. Linux mint 18.2 fast write speed (~ 2gb/s) with same 970 EVO NVME SSD.

Comment: Try this running 22.04 live and report back.

Comment: 970 evo 2TB - luks encrypted read is 1.2 GB/s, non encrypted 1.9 GB/s, haven't tested write. 5.15.0-47-generic, ubuntu 22.04, no extra configurations